# iTunes Connect watchOS2 App Error

Tags: app-store-connect, watchos-2

I am seeing the following warning in iTunes Connect when I add a build to an app version:

> Your binary doesn’t support Apple Watch. The screenshots for Apple
>   Watch won’t be shown on the App Store.

[image: screenshot of iTunes Connect]

The bundle does include an Apple watchOS2 native app, and it installs fine over TestFlight.

Is there anything I should do to resolve this issue, or does iTunes Connect not yet recognize native watchOS2 apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I posted this question, although Apple had released Xcode 7 GM, iTunes Connect did not have support for the submission of iOS 9 and watchOS 2 apps.

Today, Apple released the following press release, and I was able to submit my watchOS 2 app with no errors.

[image: Apple Developer Press Release]

Press Release: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09112015a